# Sum Between dates

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to sum all invoices that were sent the previous month, and are still outstanding, however I am getting a sum that doesn't make sense.

I am using this formula

```
=sumifs('Invoices Sent'!K:K,'Invoices Sent'!B:B,"<"&B2, 'Invoices Sent'!N:N,">="&B3)
```

It accesses a sheet called Invoices Sent where the date the invoice was sent is in column B of that sheet, and the date the invoice was paid is in column N of that sheet, and column K contains the invoice amount.

Is there something wrong with this logic ?

Any help will be appreciated !

Comment: You may need to use a equal `=` sign for first criteria `"<="&B2`. If B2 contains first date or start date then use greater than or equal like `">="&B2` and obviously second criteria will be   less than or equal `"<="&B3`.

Comment: Thanks @Harun24hr for the comment. I think your suggestion will give me the sum of invoices sent and paid within the month. I am trying to sum the invoices that were sent prior to the month, and have not been paid within the month.

Comment: `sum the invoices that were sent prior to the month, and have not been paid within the month` This is OK, and easily doable but, if I may respectfully suggest, it is NOT what the question says. The question says `sum all invoices that were sent the previous month, and are still outstanding`. Would you please edit your question to describe exactly what date range for invoices sent, AND for payments received you want to cover. In situations like this, a small set of sample data can be very useful to demonstrate the outcome that you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sum the invoices that were sent prior to the month, and have not been paid within the month`

**SUMIFS**

`=sumifs('Invoices Sent'!$K$2:$K$43,'Invoices Sent'!$B$2:$B$43,"<="&$B$2,'Invoices Sent'!$N$2:$N$43,"")+sumifs('Invoices Sent'!$K$2:$K$43,'Invoices Sent'!$B$2:$B$43,"<="&$B$2,'Invoices Sent'!$N$2:$N$43,">"&$B$2)`

**QUERY**

`=query({'Invoices Sent'!A1:N43},"select SUM(Col11) where  Col2 <= date '"&TEXT(B2, "e-m-d")&"' and (Col14 is null or Col14 > date '"&TEXT(B2, "e-m-d")&"') label SUM(Col11) ''")`

**FILTER**

`=sum(filter('Invoices Sent'!K1:K43,'Invoices Sent'!B1:B43<=B2,( 'Invoices Sent'!N1:N43="")+('Invoices Sent'!N1:N43>B2)))`

**TODAY'S DATE**

`=TODAY()`

**Last Month End**

`=EOMONTH(B1,-1)`

---

**SAMPLE RESULTS**

[image: results mark2]

---

**SAMPLE DATA**

[image: sample data]

Answer (score 0):

Here are two options for getting the total of all invoices sent last month and are still outstanding.

**SUMIFS**

`=sumifs('Invoices Sent'!$K$2:$K$43,'Invoices Sent'!$B$2:$B$43,">="&$B$1,'Invoices Sent'!$B$2:$B$43,"<="&B2,'Invoices Sent'!$N$2:$N$43 ,"")`

**QUERY**

`=query({'Invoices Sent'!A1:N43},"select Sum(Col11) where (Col2 >= date '"&TEXT(B1, "e-m-d")&"' and Col2 <= date '"&TEXT(B2, "e-m-d")&"' and Col14 is null) label Sum(Col11) '' ")`

**LOGIC**

The logic is similar in each case:

- "Date sent" is greater than or equal to (`>=`) month start.
  **AND**
- "Date sent" is less than or equal to (`<=`) month end.
  **AND**
- "Date Paid" is null/empty/blank ("")

Note about the sample data:

- there are O/S July invoices not included in the total
- there are August invoices paid *after* August (paid in September) that are NOT included in the total (because they are not still outstanding).

---

**SAMPLE RESULT**

[image: result]

Note:

- **Month start**:  `=EOMONTH(TODAY(),-2)+1`
- **Month End**: `=EOMONTH(TODAY(),-1)`

**SAMPLE DATA**

[image: sample]

Comment: Thanks @Tedinoz for the answer and the detail. Much appreciated. However isn't the sum of the invoices sent prior to August and still outstanding at the end of August, the sum of K5:K8, and not 386?

Comment: I did wonder about the July invoices (and I mentioned them in the answer) but **I answered the question that you asked**. `sum all invoices that were sent the previous month, and are still outstanding,` The invoices send **in the previous month** AND still outstanding are #: 11,12,13,14,15,22,23,24,25,26,31,32,33,34,35,36 (total $386). Regarding K5:K8 those invoices (#: 4,5,6,7; total=$22) were sent in _July_.  Your question says `sent the previous month`; it is 4 September today so the previous month = August 2023.

Comment: `However isn't the sum of the invoices sent prior to August and still outstanding at the end of August, the sum of K5:K8, and not 386?` I did a second answer for all the "old" outstanding invoices at the end of the month